# Disabling the cells and changing their color in datePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I am trying to disable some date intervals based on data I get from a database using an API. I managed to disable the cells that are contained in the intervals I get from the database but for some reason I can't find a solution to change the bg color of the disabled dates.

Here is the code I have so far:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxUrl,
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    for (var i in response) {
      console.log(response[i]);
      daysInInterval = (new Date(response[i].end_date).getTime() - new Date(response[i].start_date).getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

      for (var ii = 0; ii < daysInInterval; ii++) {
        nextDate = new Date(new Date(response[i].start_date).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * (ii + 1));
        if ((nextDate.getMonth() + 1) / 10 < 1) {
          var thisMonth = '0' + (nextDate.getMonth() + 1);
        } else {
          var thisMonth = nextDate.getMonth() + 1;
        }
        datesToBeDisabled.push(('' + nextDate.getFullYear() + '-' + thisMonth + '-' + nextDate.getDate() + '').toString());

      }
      datesToBeDisabled.push(('' + new Date(response[i].start_date).getFullYear() + '-' + thisMonth + '-' + new Date(response[i].start_date).getDate() + '').toString());
      alert(datesToBeDisabled);

    };

  },
  error: function(response) {
    alert('this failed');
  },
})


$("#datepickerStart").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [datesToBeDisabled.indexOf(string) == -1]
  },
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
});
```

I tried editing the class that is used from `jquery.ui.css` but that had no effect, or when I had it messed up the entire table

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom disable date class. The thing you have to consider when you are returning the disable array is that you have to return the class you want to apply.
if you read the below document it shows [0] - true or false [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSJ0n.png) - css class.

https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay[image]